# PHP Login Personalised Content

Tags: php

i would like a user to get its own personalised content when they log in. I have tried using the following codes but it seems when i log in the only the first user in my database appears

```
if (isset($_POST['memlogin'])) {
    extract($_POST);


    $pass = $con->command("SELECT * FROM memlogin WHERE 
            email = '".$email."' AND
            password = '".$password."'

        ");

    $res = $pass->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);



    if (empty($res)) {


        $_SESSION['messge'] =  '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                Login failed
              </div>';

        header("Location:../memlogin.php");

    }else{

        $_SESSION['admin'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['mem_id'] = $memberid;


        header("Location:../dazhboard.php");


    }
```

Comment: Use parameterized queries. You are open to SQL injections. Passwords should be hashed. Also `Do not use extract() on untrusted data, like user input` -http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Answer (score 0):

Question is not clear enough. Please repeat it in more clear way

Comment: I'm trying to develop a method of identifying which user is logged in, and depending who it is, display particular content within that page. The content of each user is different